# Show that $K_{\epsilon}$ is open. Is it also closed?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\epsilon \gt 0$

$$K_{\epsilon}=\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : 2 ||x||_{2} \lt ||x||_{1}+ \sqrt{n} ||x||_{\infty}+\epsilon \}$$

I can use that given norms are continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$. My idea is to define a function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $$f(x)=||x||_{1}+ \sqrt{n} ||x||_{\infty}+\epsilon - 2||x||_{2} $$

$f$ is continuous so preimage of every open set is open set. Now I have to determine if $K_{\epsilon}$ is closed. I don't know what ideas could I use. Maybe prove that there exists sequence in $K_{\epsilon}$ which has limit outside of it?

Comment: Hint: if it's also closed, then it is equal to $\Bbb R^n$. Now find $x \in \Bbb R^n \setminus K_{\epsilon}$.

Comment: You are correct. So I have to actually guess $x$? Or should I calculate it somehow?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea how one can sketch that. Of course you should sketch nothing. Maybe take $x=(\epsilon/k, \ldots,\epsilon/k)$, calculate the whole thing and then choose $k$ appropriately so that the inequality fails.

Answer (score 1):

We could write the condition in your set as: 
$$||x||_2  - ||x||_1  + ||x||_2 -  \sqrt n||x||_{\infty} \lt \epsilon$$
Now, you should know, by norm equivalence that $$||x||_1 \ge ||x||_2$$ and $$\sqrt n||x||_{\infty} \ge ||x||_2$$
Therefore, $$||x||_2  - ||x||_1  + ||x||_2 -  \sqrt n||x||_{\infty} \le 0 \lt \epsilon$$ 
And since the condition is satisfied $ \forall x \in \mathbb R^n$, our set $K_\epsilon$ equals $\mathbb R^n$ and is thus closed.